# How to return spaces from a plugin in LCDHype?

Tags: string, delphi, plugins, pascal

I have written a plugin for LCDHype using Delphi and I want to return a string which contains spaces. Here is an example:

```
...

implementation

...

var
  gReturnValue: String;

// Plugin.Foo.GetBar
function Library_GetBar(const AParameter: PScriptFunctionImplementationParameter): PWideChar; stdcall;
begin
  gReturnValue := 'This is a bar';

  result := PWideChar(gReturnValue);
end;
```

These spaces are removed from the string by the application somehow and never get displayed.

How can I solve this?

---

Disclosure: I'm the author of LCDHype

Comment: I'm afraid it is not at all clear from your q why a space would be any more of a problem to include in a string than any other character.

Comment: Fix the plugin so it won't require quoted strings on input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of a plugin is parsed by LCDHype meaning the return value is basically script code.

This also means that you have to return a *string* when you want to preserve the spaces. A *string* begins and ends with a `'` character like

```
'This is a bar'
```

In Delphi you need to escape the `'` characters hence the value would be

```
'''This is a bar'''
```

You can use `QuotedStr()` to escape the `'` characters and quote the string properly, for example:

```
uses SysUtils; // for QuotedStr()

...

function Library_GetBar(const AParameter: PScriptFunctionImplementationParameter): PWideChar; stdcall;
begin
  gReturnValue := QuotedStr('This is a bar');

  result := PWideChar(gReturnValue);
end;
```